# How to populate data from one element to another on click with knockout.js

Tags: javascript, html, data-binding, mvvm, knockout.js

I'd like to populate a popup with the data of the element that was clicked. For example, I have a list of users with their name, position, etc. Then when I click 'view more', a popup shows up with the same user data that was in the list item.
At the moment nothing is get written in the popup.

Please see example here: http://jsfiddle.net/46LJ9/

JS/KO

```
//should be a json from server
var users = [
  {
    "name": "Yoshi",
    "surname": "Kawasaki",
    "position": "Developer"
  },
  {
    "name": "Miu",
    "surname": "Furinji",
    "position": "Martial Artist"
  },
  {
    "name": "Shigure",
    "surname": "Kosaka",
    "position": "Martial Artist Master"
  },
  {
    "name": "Ore",
    "surname": "Ore Ga",
    "position": "Martial Artist and Developer"
  }
  ];

  (function($, ko, window) {

    var UserModel = {

    name: ko.observable(''),
    surname: ko.observable(''),
    position: ko.observable(''),

    users: ko.observableArray(users),

    userDetails: ko.observable({}),

    showOverlay: function(o) {

        UserModel.userDetails(o);

        $('.overlay, .overlay-bg').fadeIn(400, function() {
            $(this).removeClass('hide').addClass('show');
        });
    },

    closeOverlay: function(o, e) {
        $('.overlay, .overlay-bg').fadeOut(400, function() {

            var $this = $(this);

            $this
                .removeClass('show')
                .addClass('hide')
                .removeAttr('style');
        });
    }

  };

  ko.applyBindings(UserModel);

}(jQuery, ko, window));
```

Comment: it'll be easier to look at if you create a jsfiddle demonstrating the issue

Comment: I was thinking of doing it with jsfiddle. But in the past, I used to do it in jsfiddle and got many complaints... I'll update the question shortly. Check back in about 5mins, @Tanner. Many Thanks

Comment: It's in jsfiddle now: http://jsfiddle.net/46LJ9/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your JS, you're updating `UserModel.userDetails(o);` but your html is binding to `name` etc.

```
<h1><span class="name" data-bind="text: name"></span></h1>
```

Change the binding to `data-bind="text: userDetails().name"` and it will work.

Either that, or update your name, surname and position observables.

See: http://jsfiddle.net/46LJ9/1/

EDIT

Obviously using a with binding makes more sense than the above:

```
<div class="overlay hide" data-bind="with: userDetails">
```

Seen here: http://jsfiddle.net/46LJ9/3/

Comment: Thanks @RobH. It works when I use your 1st technique with `userDetails().name, etc`, but with your 2nd technique using `with:` it throws an error, saying `ReferenceError: surname is not defined` in firebug.. Why is that? Btw, I'm using knockout 3.0.